# Convert int to time and add two times in java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the duration of a reservation and convert it to time so that I can update the `end time` of the reservation. Say the user enters the start time as `18:05:00` and the total duration is `15` (which is the total minutes for reservation), I would wanna convert `15` into minutes say `00:15:00` and wanna get the result as `18:25:00`.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 15 minutes after 18:05 is 18:20, not 18:25.

You can use the [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class to store your time, and add n minutes to it.

```
LocalTime originalTime = LocalTime.parse("18:05:00");
int minutes = 15; // replace this with the user input
LocalTime newTime = originalTime.plusMinutes(minutes)
System.out.println(newTime);
```

To store "15 minutes", you can use the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class.

Comment: is there a way to add like 21:05:00?

Comment: @Dhirish you mean 21 hours and 5 minutes?